# Logging additional custom information in PHPUnit for reports

Tags: selenium, report, reporting, phpunit

I am using PHPUnit Selenium for functional testing of my project.
I am using junit for logging and using the log file to gnerate the report. Following is the log tag in phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit>
 <logging>
  <log type="junit" target="reports/logfile.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false" />
 </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Then I use the logfile.xml to generate the report.

What I am looking for is the ability to log additional information (information telling what exactly is getting tested in assertion, in both cases i.e. in both pass/fail of assertion).

Basically in reports I want to tell what is being asserted. And that information will be written by the test writer in the test case manually along with assertion.

`assert` functions comes with the third optional parameter as message but that is shown only on failure.

Eg:

```
<?php
// $accountExists is the dummy variable which wil probably checking in database for the existence of the record
$this->assertEquals(true, $accountExists, 'Expecting for accountExists to be true');
?>
```

Above will return message on failure but not when test is passed.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the

--printer command line argument to point to a custom printer class

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener

in your endTest function whatever you put in printf will show up in your log file.